# Regex to extract (full match) word from last but one, between comma?

Tags: regex

How to return the word example in the result column?
the closest I got was [\W]{2,}[^,\W].+[?=,]

| id | text | my result (Full match) | expected (Full match) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | wordA, worldB, wordC | , worldB, | wordB |
| 2 | wordF wordY, worldZ, wordn, wordM | , worldZ, wordn, | wordn |
| 3 | wordg wordt, worldl, wordq, wordk, wordr | , worldl, wordq, wordk, | wordk |
| 4 | this is a test, capturing, a word | , capturing, | capturing |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one:

```
(?!\s)[^,]+?(?=\s*,[^,]*$)
```

- `(?!\s)` make sure is not capturing the first white space
- `[^,]+?` anything that not a comma, non-greedy
- `(?=\s*,[^,]*$)` possitive look ahead, there is a comma seperated word in front of it before the end of the string

It also trims the white spaces at both ends.

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Xe6j8e/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This regex looks at the end of the string `$`, capturing the word `(\w+)` before the last comma `\,` and last word `[\w\s]+`

https://regex101.com/r/42NELQ/1

```
(\w+)\,[\w\s]+$
```

Comment: Although, it works back in a group. The goal is to return the full game. But it is a valid option, thank you!